# create column that is minimum of computed values on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like:

```
                SA         MA       SB       MB
2015-08-31       100       60       80       25
2015-08-31       100       60       80       25
2015-09-30       90        90       75       70
2015-10-31       34        12       65       6
```

I can create a new column that is say divides two columns:
df.new_col = df.SA/df.MA

but what I need to do is, for each row, create a new column that is the minimum of [SA/MA, SB/MB]

I tried

```
df['new_col'] = min((df.SA / df.MA), (df.SB / df.MB))
```

but I get an error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.minimum`.

Updated after @DSM's pointer.

```
In [148]: df['new_col'] = pd.np.minimum(df.SA / df.MA, df.SB / df.MB)

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
             SA  MA  SB  MB   new_col
2015-08-31  100  60  80  25  1.666667
2015-08-31  100  60  80  25  1.666667
2015-09-30   90  90  75  70  1.000000
2015-10-31   34  12  65   6  2.833333
```

You could explicitly use numpy arrays like `pd.np.minimum((df.SA / df.MA).values, (df.SB / df.MB).values)`

Comment: Do you even need the `.values`?  For me it behaves as it should without them (with modern numpy & pandas -- I *think* numpy didn't used to play as nicely with Series as it does now.)

Comment: You're right. I was being explicit there. Updated the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I like this as the most straightforward, so I selected it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dataframe from 2 series and then get the min.

```
df['new_col'] = pd.DataFrame([df.SA / df.MA, df.SB / df.MB]).min()
```

Comment: A typo there, and it would throw `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: I meant, `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['new_col'] = pd.concat([df['SA']/df['MA'], df['SB']/df['MB']], axis=1).min(axis=1)

         Date   SA  MA  SB  MB   new_col
0  2015-08-31  100  60  80  25  1.666667
1  2015-08-31  100  60  80  25  1.666667
2  2015-09-30   90  90  75  70  1.000000
3  2015-10-31   34  12  65   6  2.833333
```